# discord.js suggestions - Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I've been making a suggestion command and I don't know what the current problem is, please help.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestions',
    aliases: ['suggest', 'suggestion'],
    permissions: [],
    description: 'creates a suggestions!',
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord){
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'suggestions');
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send('suggestions channel does not exist!');
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DiscordBots\commands\suggestions.js:7:39)
```

Here's my main file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})


client.login('MYTOKEN');
```

Here's where I run execute() i think:

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = '-';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

Comment: If `message.guild` is `undefined`, chances are you're passing the arguments to `execute` in the wrong order. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66334543/edit) and add the code how you call the `execute()` function in your main file?

Comment: i added main file and where execute is

Answer (score 0):

Please try to define channel and then send message

```
client.channels.cache.get("CHANNELID").send(`TEST`);
```

Comment: where do I put that

Comment: Zsolt probably right you must show us how you call `execute()` function, you probably made arguments wrong.

Comment: i edit it and added the main file and where execute is

Comment: check my last comment, change execute() args' of suggestion command then

Comment: change it to what and do i still need to use that if(command) command.execute(message, null, null, client, Discord) in my message.js?

Comment: dont forget to approve the commet, so any people with this problem will understand

Answer (score 0):

this may be work;

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestions',
    aliases: ['suggest', 'suggestion'],
    permissions: [],
    description: 'creates a suggestions!',
    execute(client, message, args, Discord){ // CHANGED
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'suggestions');
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send('suggestions channel does not exist!');
    }
}
```